# Hash function for good sorting/comparison for 6 integers

Tags: c++, optimization, hash, set

I was playing with a problem here... I managed to solve it using the following:

```
 struct wrap
 {
    char grid[7];
    bool operator==(const wrap &segundo) const
    {
        return !strcmp(segundo.grid, grid);
    }
    bool operator<(const wrap &segundo) const
    {
         return strcmp(grid, segundo.grid) < 0;
    }
    //other stuff here
 }
```

Now I'm trying to see if working with 6 integers instead of that array would improve the speed:

```
 struct wrap
 {
    int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3; 

    bool operator==(const wrap &segundo) const
    {
        return x1 == segundo.x1 && x2 == segundo.x2 && x3 == segundo.x3 && y1 == segundo.y1 && y2 == segundo.y2 && y3 == segundo.y3;
    }
    bool operator<(const wrap &segundo) const
    {       
        return ??? // I want to know a good thing to put here... 
                       // I have some Ideas but would appreciate suggestions
    }
```

Let me explain a little better the situation: I'm using a set and I started playing with sets yesterday so I don't know much about it...

I know it requires operator< to know how to sort the elements... but does it use my definition of operator== when using the find method? or it would be doing inversion in the order of elements while comparing and that is it?

If the answer to the previous question is second possibility, will it behave differently if the struct implement operator== (since the < is provided by the programmer, it is feasable that it might take advantage of other operator that might be provided to avoid some negations?)

Going back to my code, I thought about:

```
 return 100000*x1 + 10000*y1 + 1000*x2 + 100*y2 + 10*x3 + y3 - (same sum for the second) > 0;
```

One last question: the values that those 6 ints can have is in [0, 9], changing them to shorts or chars will give any speed improvement or just memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the container knows about your object is that it has an operator< so. operator== if it exists will not be used.

The operator< that you supply must be a vaild one in the sense that:

`if not x<y and not y<x ==>  y==x`

The simplest operator< for a series is a dictionary compare.

The sorted_set (default c++ set) will use operator< keep the set in order and will find from the set in O(lgN)
unorderd_set will use a hash function which assuming a decent hash function will perform better then set on all but the smallest sets and will not allow to make any assumptions about item order.

EDIT:
The problem with your operator< is likely one of overflow. unless you know the MAX value for x1, x2, x3 etc.. then your suggestion is likely to produce wrong results.

x1*1000000 might pass MAX_INT in which case it will become a huge negative value.
x2 might be larger then 10,000  in case it is big and x1 is small then again you will get wrong results.

My first attempt will be to use something like

```
   std::tie(x1, x2, x3 ... ) < std::tie(o.x1, o.x2, o.x3, ...)
```

which keeps the code readable and in essence it is a dictionary compare:

```
if (x1== o.x1) {
    if (x2== o.x2) { 
       if (x3 == o.x3 {
          ...
       } else { 
           return x3 < o.x3;
       }
    } else {
      return x2 < o.x2;
    }
} else {
    return x1 < o.x1;
}
```

Comment: and about a way to implement my < function, any idea or suggestion?

Comment: If you need fast then try `unordered_map` producing a valid hash function is not difficult and the number of tests needed before access can be greatly reduced.

Make sure that you need the speed and you are not optimizing for optimization sake

Comment: Using `std::tie` is the idiomatic way and at least as efficient as `std::make_tuple`. Not sure why you recommended that first.

Comment: I doubt a reference to an int will be different from a copy of an int.. but point taken and std::make_tuple removed

Comment: @odedsh I don't necessarily need the speed... it is a 400+ line code, I implemented in a different way just to get some notion about what would be better to do in each case... training for the ACM ICPC competition and exploring the data structures in the standard library... The time limit for this problem is 2 seconds, my first submission had time 1.088, I changed a few things and went to 1.016. Then I decided to implement with 6 int to see if would change much, since someone solved in 0.116

Comment: @odedsh I tried those comparisons but the feedback was time limit exceeded haha... I did multiplying like i said and time was 0.912, I changed from int to char, time dropped to 0.884

Comment: Then try a union of a char[6] array and long like Mike suggested below. 
You can use the array to access the data when you need the actual data and the long representation to perform the comparison in a single 64bit operation

Answer (score 2):

> does it use my definition of operator== when using the find method?

No.

> would be doing inversion in the order of elements while comparing and that is it?

That's right. It finds a key that's *equivalent* under the comparison operation, not necessarily *equal*, to its argument. Keys `k1` and `k2` are equivalent if

```
!(k1 < k2) && !(k2 < k1)
```

> will it behave differently if the struct implement `operator==`

No. Ordered associative containers only use a single comparison operation - by default `std::less<key_type>`, which by default uses `operator<`. Even if you provide an equality operator, it won't necessarily give the same result as the equivalence test that the container needs, so the container can't use it.

> changing them to shorts or chars will give any speed improvement or just memory?

There's a good chance that it will, but it's something you'll need to measure. Likewise, the only way to tell whether the branch-free arithmetic comparison you suggest would be better than a lexicographical comparison (like `strcmp`/`memcmp` or tuple comparisons) is by measuring.

Another possibility is to compare them all in a single 64-bit operation:

```
union {
    uint8_t bytes[8]; // Make sure unused bytes are set to zero
    uint64_t all;
} grid;

bool operator<(const wrap &segundo) const {
    return grid.all < segundo.grid.all;
}
```

You might also like to investigate `std::unordered_set`, a hashed container which can be more efficient if you don't care about the order of the elements.

Comment: but then I would have to provide the key for this unordered set, and I need all 6 for the key, wouldn't it end up in the same situation?

Comment: @nightshade: Yes, you'll still need to provide a hash function and equality comparison for `unordered_set`. I just mentioned it as something you might consider as an alternative to an ordered `std::set`, if you're looking for the most efficient way to manage a set.

Comment: I saw the documentation and it says its C++11, last year I think the competition didn't allow C++11, so I'm trying to focus on structures that I'll be able to use there... thanks for the hints tho!